# How do I use a Tkinter Button for two states?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have the following code, which causes a color/text change when a Tkinter button is clicked. I would like to revert to the original color/text when the button is clicked a second time.

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Start/Stop Button")
window.geometry('200x100')

def clicked_rf1():
    btn_rf1.configure(text="Stop")
    lbl_rf1.configure(text="  ON  ", bg="green")

btn_rf1 = Button(window, text="Start", command=clicked_rf1)
btn_rf1.grid(column=1, row=1)
lbl_rf1 = Label(window, text="  OFF ", bg="red")
lbl_rf1.grid(column=2, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

I want something that behaves a little more like a toggle, but I would like the look of a button.

Help gratefully received.

Comment: Do you want the button to toggle or the label?

Comment: The text/color change is just an example. In reality, I would like to run pile of code A on the first click and pile of code B on the second click. So, I guess the button.

Comment: In that case I think Novel's answer should provide a good example for both the button and label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need an if block to choose what to do. You can make another flag variable to keep track of the state, or just use the current Label or Button text:

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Start/Stop Button")
window.geometry('200x100')

def clicked_rf1():
    if btn_rf1['text'] == "Start":
        btn_rf1.configure(text="Stop")
        lbl_rf1.configure(text="  ON  ", bg="green")
    else:
        btn_rf1.configure(text="Start")
        lbl_rf1.configure(text="  OFF ", bg="red")

btn_rf1 = Button(window, text="Start", command=clicked_rf1)
btn_rf1.grid(column=1, row=1)
lbl_rf1 = Label(window, text="  OFF ", bg="red")
lbl_rf1.grid(column=2, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

This would be an ideal place to make a custom Button subclass, so you could have many of these in your program:

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Start/Stop Button")
window.geometry('200x100')

class Christina(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        self.btn = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.clicked)
        self.btn.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.lbl = Label(self, text="  OFF ", bg="red")
        self.lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)

    def clicked(self):
        if self.btn['text'] == "Start":
            self.btn.configure(text="Stop")
            self.lbl.configure(text="  ON  ", bg="green")
        else:
            self.btn.configure(text="Start")
            self.lbl.configure(text="  OFF ", bg="red")

btn1 = Christina(window)
btn1.grid()
btn2 = Christina(window)
btn2.grid()
btn3 = Christina(window)
btn3.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You beet me to it :D. One thing thought. You may want to add the globals for the toggle function. I know python will eventually check global even if its not provided but I think its best for the OP and others learning.

Comment: Or use a `dict` mapping current state to next state.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks all!

Comment: Why is your `Button` inheriting from `Frame`?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque because OP wanted a Button and a Label combined, so I used a Frame to hold those 2.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a toggle, you can use the checkbutton without an indicator. It has options for the color in the selected and deselected state, and you can tie the value and the label together so that the label changes when you toggle the button.

Like any button, you can tie a command to it. The command can check the value of the variable to determine whether it should do the "on" function or the "off" function.

Here's a simple example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def toggle():
    if var.get() == "ON":
        print("turning on...")
    else:
        print("turning off...")

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
toggle = tk.Checkbutton(root, onvalue="ON", offvalue="OFF", width=4,
                        indicatoron=False, 
                        variable=var, textvariable=var,
                        selectcolor="green", background="red",
                        command=toggle)

var.set("OFF")
toggle.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach might be to put the "pile of code" to run into different function, collect those in an iterator, and then get the `next` function from that iterator and execute it:

```
def bunchofcode():
    print("foo")

def somethingelse():
    print("bar")

whattodo = iter([bunchofcode, somethingelse])

def clicked_rf1():
    try:
        next(whattodo)()
    except StopIteration:
        print("nothing to do")
```

Or for cyclic behaviour:

```
from itertools import cycle
whattodo = cycle([bunchofcode, somethingelse])
```

---

For a two-state toggle button, you could also use a `dict` to map the current state to the next. You could also use the button's `relief` to mark the state.

```
def clicked_rf1():
    transition = {"raised": "sunken", "sunken": "raised"}
    btn_rf1["relief"] = transition[btn_rf1["relief"]]
```